# SharpDevelop XSHD file for Ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby, sharpdevelop, avalonedit

Has anyone written an AvalonEdit XSHD file for Ruby syntax? I'm in need of one for my project and I want to make sure I'm not re-inventing the wheel. Thanks

Comment: There's a project to make an AvalonEdit based IDE for Ruby: http://code.google.com/p/yuzhenpin-nemo/ – check if they provide the file you need?

Comment: @Inerdia good pointer, but couldn't find one there, I will keep an eye on that project

Comment: There's one in their SVN repo: http://code.google.com/p/yuzhenpin-nemo/source/browse/trunk/lib/nemo/xshd/ruby.xml

Comment: Silly me, didn't see it, please add is as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/yuzhenpin-nemo) to make an AvalonEdit based IDE for Ruby. They seem to have a [XSHD file for Ruby](http://code.google.com/p/yuzhenpin-nemo/source/browse/trunk/lib/nemo/xshd/ruby.xml) in their SVN repo.

Comment: SharpDevelop does include its own Ruby syntax highlighting, stored separately from AvalonEdit, which that Google Code project seems to have used -  https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/blob/master/src/AddIns/BackendBindings/Ruby/RubyBinding/Project/Resources/Ruby.xshd